# В чем отличие htons  от htonl и зачем нужен short и long порядок байт?

Tags: сокет, c++

Сообственно я понимаю, что сетевой порядок и порядок хоста отличается. 
Интересно когда нужен short и зачем его использовать?
(В голове "непонятка").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В протоколе IPv4 адрес хоста имеет размер 4 байта, для него надо применять htonl() и переменные типа int (на 32-разрядных машинах можно long. 16-разрядные для простоты забудем).

Адрес порта в IP имеет размер 2 байта, соответственно htons() и short.

Адреса хоста и порта передаются по сети и их биты должны быть упорядочены единообразно.

Answer (score 1):

short (2 байта) int (на некоторых платформах 4 байта) long (8 байт) - это типы данных (размер). 
Зачем эти типы данных? Ну программисты склонны использовать различные типы данных в свих программах. :)

Comment: Я понимаю. Но использую ли сейчас для хранения сетевого адреса short?

Comment: Смотрите на эти функции не как на средство для работы с адрсами, а как полезные функции для работы с данными.
Это может пригодиться, когда вам необходимо передать данные через сокет между платформами у которых порядок байт отличается.
И тогда вам не придется наварачивать протокол обмена, не потребуетеся жестко зашивать в коде некие проверки, а просто при отправке данных в сокет переводите их в порядок сети, при получении переводите в порядок хоста. Для чисел с плавоющей точкой такой фокус не пройдет. :)

Answer (score 1):

Тип это не размер. Это смысловое значение.

Answer (score 0):

short и long - пережиток BSD. Вообще советую почитать Стивенса, чтобы "непоняток" было меньше. И да, short и long - это не порядок байт.

Comment: Это не порядок байт, это тип для хранения байт.
Правильно?